# How to set an alias for a background process in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, bash, python, process

I have a bunch of Python scripts that are executed on startup and run in the background.

My startups scripts are in the form of:

```
pythonw aScript.py
pythonw anotherScript.py
```

I want to be able to give these scripts an alias so in the process list they appear as those alias instead of just `pythonw.exe` for both.

Is there a way to do this on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) to create Windows Services than run in the background. It takes 2 minutes to set up.